How to keep footer at the very bottom of the page (Vuetify)?
I've checked all questions and answers related to this issue on Stackoverflow, but nothing helped in my case. That's why I'm asking again.
We have Vue 3 app and use the latest Vuetify library.
The issue with footer looks as following:


As you can see the footer moved up. I need it to stay at the very bottom.
The code looks as following:
<template>
    <v-app>
        <app-header />

        <v-toolbar fixed="true" dense>
        ...
        </v-toolbar>

        <router-view />

        <app-footer class="no-overlap" />
    </v-app>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
    .no-overlap {
        position: relative !important;
        max-height: 50px !important;
    }
    ...
}

